# error instantiating redBlackTree template

Tags: d, template-meta-programming, dmd

I'm having trouble instantiating a RedBlackTree container with chars, but it works with ints:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.container;

void main()
{
        auto r1 = redBlackTree!(int)();   // works
        auto r2 = redBlackTree!(char)();  // error instantiating
}
```

I'm using DMD32 D Compiler v2.060.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: the type needs to be comparable or you need to provide a comparator (apparently it doesn't consider `char` to be comparable try `dchar` instead)

Comment: @ratchetfreak that worked, thanks. Any idea why? Post your answer and I will mark it correct.

Comment: Note: if you a looking for an 8 bit number use `byte` or `ubyte`, and if you need an associative container from that to `T` consider `T[256]` or `(T*)[256]`, it might be smaller and will be faster than a tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to use a type that is comparable (i.e. can use the < operator or provide your own comparator as the second template parameter

`char` (and wchar) is only useful for use in arrays due to one `char` not necessarily relating to an actual letter in unicode (UTF8 edition) this has other gotcha that will trip up new coders in D

`dchar` on the other hand will always correspond to a letter and as such is comparable to another letter,

rule of thumb in D always use `dchar` unless it's for a string type (and even then consider using dstring)